# Except function is giving me a syntax error

Tags: python

I am trying to attempt to determine someones pay check by having them put the amount of hours they worked and their pay rate. I am getting a SyntaxError with my "Except:" I tried to change my "else" with a "elif" but that gives me a SyntaxError for the "elif" statement. For the pay scale if the person works 40 hours they get payed the amount of hours multiplied by the pay rate, if they worked more then 40 hours they get payed 1.5 hours for all hours worked above 40. Any help would be much appreciated!!

```
try:
  HoursWorked = int(input("How many hours did you work? "))
  Rate = int(input("How much is your hourly rate? "))
  if HoursWorked <= 40:
    print(HoursWorked * Rate)
  else HoursWorked > 40: 
    print(((40*PayRate)+((HoursWorked-40)*(1.5*PayRate)))
except:
  print("Error, please enter a number.")
```

Comment: You have an unmatched opening parenthesis character `(` in the line preceding the `except` token.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `else HoursWorked > 40:`. You can use either `elif HoursWorked > 40:` or only `else:`. Then you have unmatching parenthesis in the line above `except`.